# How to create models without ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My web app uses MongoDB and because the data isn't relational or complex I rather not use any of the MongoDB ODMs like Mongoid. Also the MongoDb driver is supposed to be many times faster than it's available ODMs.

Does ActiveRecord provide things that I can utilise in a basic Model or should I just create a basic class that knows how to access MongoDB and define some methods for accessing the data?

I found [this article by Yehuda Catz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) who suggests to use ActiveModel in order to bering ActiveRecord goodness to your custom models. It sounds logical to me. Is this the right way?

Comment: You must have a look at Datamapper. It will be all you will need to power your application explicitly more better than ActiveRecord. http://datamapper.org

Comment: Also, there's [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your are right ActiveModel is the way too go if you dont intend to use ActiveRecord for a tableless model

As of Rails 3+ ActiveModel has been one of the prominent feature .

ActiveModel has all the nicety to get started with a tableless model.

Most of the ActiveRecord Validation and Callback mostly inherit from  ActiveModel .

As per using MongoDB  (**MongoId**) one of the mongodb adapter leverage the advantage of ActiveModel for validation check the validations files [here](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/tree/3.1.0-stable/lib/mongoid/validations)

Comment: @Atul I guess that ok with you